# js: value is null, typeof returns string, but comparison with null or '' returns false

Tags: node.js, koa

Am evaluating koa js for a solution, but ran through the following issue:

Have some http headers which need not always be populated by the client, means sometimes the header will be null, but on processing the header on server side comparing it for null/empty string always returns false even when it is null.

To see whats the value and what the outcome of comparison is, have traced all the possible outcomes and here are the following:

```
console.log(typeof ctx.get('X-SessionId'));
console.log(ctx.get('X-SessionId'));
console.log(!ctx.get('X-SessionId'));
console.log(ctx.get('X-SessionId') === null);
console.log(ctx.get('X-SessionId') == null);
console.log(ctx.get('X-SessionId') == '');
console.log(ctx.get('X-SessionId') === '');
console.log(ctx.get('X-SessionId').length);
```

Output :

```
string
null
false
false
false
false
false
4
```

Here the typeof returns string but the value itself is null. Comparing it with either null or '' returns false. And surprisingly .length returns 4!

Anyone has a suggestion how to overcome this comparison problem?

Comment: literal "null" = 4 chars?   Try `console.log(ctx.get('X-SessionId') === "null");`

Comment: Oh my God yes its literal 'null'. Cross checked whats being passed from client side. But there it says null and not "null". Normally any string thats passed on headers are contained in "", so am pretty sure the header is passed as null, Wondering why on the server side its taking as "null"?
Anyways thanks a lot @Emma for this suggestion.